# Check PulseAudio sink volume

Tags: 12.04, command-line, pulseaudio

Is there any command to check the PulseAudio sinks volume. Means I want display PulseAudio volume of particular sinks in %

i.e. 50%

I already set the volume using `pactl set-sinks-volume 1 50%` command. But now i want to check is it 50% or not.

So how can i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `pactl list sinks` to get info on the current state of your sinks. This returns a lot of information, including the volume. So, to get only the volume of sink 1, you can use:

```
pactl list sinks | perl -000ne 'if(/#1/){/(Volume:.*)/; print "$1\n"}'
```

This will return something like:

```
Volume: 0:  50% 1:  50%
```

The above `perl` command will print the details of `sink 1`. To use a different sink, change the `#1` to another number, for example `#0`.

I am not sure what the two `50%` mean, I assume they are the left and right speaker volumes. So, in order to check if they are above or below a specific value, (assuming that the balance is set to "center", that both left and right volumes are identical so only one needs to be checked), you can do:

```
pactl list sinks | perl -000lne 'if(/#1/){/Volume:.*?(\d+)%/; $1 >= 50 ? (print "y\n") : (print "n\n")}'
```

The above will print a `y` if the volume is greater than or equal to 50 and an `n` otherwise. This is all getting a bit complex though, so I would simplify by creating a script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl 
    
    ## The sink we are interested in should be given as the 
    ## 1st argument to the script.
    die("Need a sink number as the first argument\n") if @ARGV < 1;
    my $sink=$ARGV[0];
    
    ## If the script has been run with a second argument,
    ## that argument will be the volume threshold we are checking
    my $volume_limit=$ARGV[1]||undef;
    
    ## Run the pactl command and save the output in 
    ## ther filehandle $fh
    open(my $fh, '-|', 'pactl list sinks');
    
    ## Set the record separator to consecutive newlines (same as -000)
    ## this means we read the info for each sink as a single "line".
    $/="\n\n";
    
    ## Go through the pactl output
    while (<$fh>) {
        ## If this is the sink we are interested in
        if (/#$sink/) {
            ## Extract the current colume of this sink
            /Volume:.*?(\d+)%/;
            my $volume=$1;
            ## If the script has been run with a second argument,
            ## check whether the volume is above or below that
            if ($volume_limit) {
                ## If the volume os greater than or equal to the
                ## value passed, print "y"
                if ($volume >= $volume_limit) {
                   print "y\n";
                    exit 0;
                }
                else {
                    print "n\n";
                    exit 1;
                }
            }   
            ## Else, if the script has been run with just one argument,
            ## print the current volume.
            else {
                print "$volume%\n";
            }
        }
}
```

Save the script above as `check_volume.pl` in a directory in your `$PATH` (for example, `/usr/local/bin`), make it executable, `chmod +x check_volume.pl` and then run it giving the sink you are interested as the first argument:

```
$ check_volume.pl 1
50%
```

To check whether the volume is above a given threshold, give the threshold as a second argument:

```
$ check_volume.pl 1 50
y
$ check_volume.pl 1 70
n
```

Note that this assumes your system language is English. If it isn't run the script with a changed locale:

```
LC_ALL=C check_volume.pl 1 50
```

Comment: How can I check the volume is >= 50% in if condition

Comment: @PrakashVHolkar see updated answer, I made a more complex script.

Comment: `pactl` outputs locale-dependent strings, causing commands in this answer to fail on non-english systems. Either prefix always with `LC_ALL=C ` or type once `export LC_ALL=C` to set the shell (and all commands run from it) to the default locale. Then `pactl | perl ...` works.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon good point, answer edited, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `amixer` to read the pulseaudio volume by using the mixer option like this.

```
$ amixer -c $CARD -M -D $MIXER get $SCONTROL
# CARD is your sound card number, mixer is either alsa or pulse and scontrol is the alsa device name, Master if you want to use pulse.
$ amixer -c 1 -M -D pulse get Master

Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 27662 [42%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 27662 [42%] [on]
```

Now we can parse it using `grep` or `sed` or `perl`.

```
$ amixer -c 1 -M -D pulse get Master | grep -o -E [[:digit:]]+%
```

Answer (score 2):

This might actually be implemented as part of the pulseaudio `pactl` command at some point in the future (seen from January 2021). Non-complete list of places where progress might be tracked:

- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/660
- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/430
- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/445
- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/812